# Load a module after installing an rpm

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, rhel, rhel7

I have a custom driver which I need to install during Driver Disk update as part of Linux(RHEL) installation. Once the module is loaded, I want **ahci** module to be loaded automatically.
For this purpose, I have added `rpm -ivh kmod-ahci-xxxx.rpm` in the post install scriptlet of my custom driver rpm file.
 Followed by which I added `modprobe ahci`.
 But **ahci** module is still not getting loaded. 

What should be the exact steps?

Answer (score 1):

That is not the way to install other dependencies. You should add:

```
 Requires: kmod-ahci
```

in the spec file of your "custom driver rpm". If you are the one to generate the kmod-ahci rpm; I would suggest you add the `modprobe ahci` in the post install script of that rpm.

What concerns your question why the ahci module doesn't get loaded; I don't know like this. You should first try performing the steps by hand before packaging them in an rpm; So I would try doing manually:

```
rpm -ivh kmod-ahci-xxxx.rpm
modprobe ahci
```

and then check whether ahci is loaded or not; and if not search the reason why...

Comment: Actually I am blacklisting ahci driver in order to claim my driver first. Following which I want to load ahci driver.

Comment: In that case; if you want to uninstall another rpm; you can use `Conflicts` or `Obsoletes` in your spec file